# It is a simple source code, but it does not run

Tags: python, import

```
import tailer

test = tailer.tail(open("test.txt"), 1)
#print(lines[1])
```

It's as simple as the code above, but it doesn't work.

(I saved it because it was successful once during the experiment, but an error occurs when I run it again later.)

**Error content:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\VSCODE\python\V1\tailer.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tailer
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\VSCODE\python\V1\tailer.py", line 3, in <module>
    test = tailer.tail(open("test.txt"), 1)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tailer' has no attribute 'tail' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Obviously something's wrong so it won't work, but... I don't know what's wrong...

I am not an expert, but when I use "import" I always use it the same way....

Comment: Suspect there’s something conflict in your environment - is there suspicious files by the name ?

Comment: It looks like it should work the way it is. Try the same code with tailer.head() and see if it works

Comment: Can you share you python file name.

Comment: The python file was named tailer.py.
I changed the name to aaa.py and it ran immediately...

It was good learning.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your file is called `tailer.py`, so when it does `import tailer`, it tries to load itself, which is usually a recipe for confusion.

Answer (score -1):

You named your program `tailer.py`. When you do an `import tailer` the local folder has priority over all other folders and you will import `tailer.py` again. Creating an import circle.

In other words: you have a name clash between your program and the library you are trying to import. Just rename the file to something else and try again.